# Python SQLite3 won't execute wildcard for variable

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have created a database with sqlite3, but I can't access and retrieve data by using wildcards.

To retrive the h1 column with the value: **Case Samsung Galaxy S9**, the wildcard **'%?%'** doesn't work.

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex_query.py", line 13, in <module>
    for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE h1 LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY price", (t,)):
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

This is my code. I tried various iterations the query, but none of them seem to work.

For debugging I also inserted the string "Samsung" straight into the query and it works. By only proble is that

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')

c = conn.cursor()

t = 'Samsung'

for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE h1 LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY price", (t,)):
    print row
    print c.fetchall()
```

I have been looking for a solution for hours, but I can't locate where the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that method works unless you're using a sql that needs `VALUES`. This should work though

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE h1 LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY price".format(t))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to query from a db that has the h1 column with values as "Samsung Galaxy S7", "Case Samsung Galaxy S6", "Screen protection Samsung Galaxy S8".

I tried your solution and I get the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Samsung`.

So if somebody needs to search based on a kw, it sould return all rows that have the kw in h1 column.

Comment: Ok i made an edit, try adding the `%` back in like i did

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!

But why? I mean do you mind explaining the logic behind it as I can't seem to get it at this point.

What's the difference between `'&?&'` and the working solution `'&{}&'`? Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. As i understand it, the `'%?%'` method can be used for `INSERT INTO` sql statements. There maybe be extra sql injection protection built into this method, not sure. But the db didn't know what to do with the extra parameters, `t` in this case, you gave it so it threw an error. The `.format` method is a string tool built into python. It automatically formats whatever you give it and inserts it into `{}` in the string. This happens before the sql gets send to the db, so it just looks like a string to the execute method. If that helped, feel free to accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You saved my day :)